# MouseOut Event from ONLY the top

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the mouseOut event handler, but I want to restrain the event to fire when the mouse exits from the TOP ONLY——not from the right, left or bottom.

```
var executed = false;

function mouseoutHandler(e){
  window.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler, false);
    executed = true;
    document.getElementById(“element”).style.width = "300px";
}

function runOnce() {
  window.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler, false);
};


runOnce();
```

What can I add to make it only fire when the mouseOut is from the top of my element ?

Comment: 1) test if it's on the top in any way you see fit in the event handler. 2) use event.preventDefault to cancel event bubbling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `clientY` is smaller than the `offsetTop` from your element. 

Only if the mouse cursor leaves on the top, this is the case

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('element');
var executed = false;

const mouseoutHandler = (e) => {
  if(e.clientY <= myElement.offsetTop) {
    myElement.style.width = '100px';
    executed = true;
    myElement.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
  }
}

myElement.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler, false);
```

```css
body{height:100vh;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}#element{width:200px;height:100px;background:#333}
```

```html
<div id="element">&nbsp;</div>
```

---

**edit**

non arrow function for IE

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('element');
var executed = false;

function mouseoutHandler(e) {
  if(e.clientY <= myElement.offsetTop) {
    myElement.style.width = '100px';
    executed = true;
    myElement.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
  }
}

myElement.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler, false);
```

```css
body{height:100vh;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}#element{width:200px;height:100px;background:#333}
```

```html
<div id="element">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: This works, but not in IE 10 or 11. is there another way to set the offsetTop that will work in IE ?

Comment: I use es6 arrow function in my example. See my edit, that should work in IE. Use `function mouseoutHandler(e) { }` instead my arrow function syntax.

Comment: That works in IE 11! (without the es6 arrow function) Awesome!! IE10 probably does not need to be supported. I think it's the clientY that IE10 doesn't recognize, do you know of any workarounds in-case IE10 needs support ?

Comment: ah ok, i hate IE10 :) Just change `const` in the first line to `var` ;) I will edit it in the IE example too.